# How to get index of max of each row every three columns of a data frame?

Tags: r, apply

I would like to find the index of the max for each row of my ldf dataframe every three columns and create a dataframe with the results.
Here below my code that works.
But, I would like to improve it and make it faster. I have tried to use apply to go throgh the rows of ldf but did not succeeded.

Here my failure:

```
ldf<-data.frame(name=c("aa","bb","cc"),V1=c(10,15,10),V2=c(20,10,8),
V3=c(8,8,9),V4=c(20,8,9),V5=c(10,15,8),V6=c(8,10,10))
pos<-NULL
index<-NULL
pos<-apply(ldf,1,function(x){
index<-sapply(seq(2, length(x), 3),function(i){
index<-NULL
cbind(index,which(x[i:(i+2)]==max(x[i:(i+2)]), arr.ind=TRUE)[2])

})
pos<-rbind(pos,index)
})

pos
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
```

Here the code that works with the expected results to be improved:

```
ldf<-data.frame(name=c("aa","bb","cc"),V1=c(10,15,10),V2=c(20,10,8),
V3=c(8,8,9),V4=c(20,8,9),V5=c(10,15,8),V6=c(8,10,10))
index<-NULL
pos<-NULL


for(x in 1:dim(ldf)[1]){
index<-sapply(seq(2, dim(ldf)[2], 3),function(i){
index<-NULL
cbind(index,which(ldf[x,i:(i+2)]==max(ldf[x,i:(i+2)]), 
    arr.ind=TRUE)[2])

    })
pos<-rbind(pos,index)
}
pos
      [,1] [,2]
index    2    1
index    1    2
index    1    3
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built in function `which.max` to determine the index of the maximum value.  So it is a matter of applying this function row by row and then group of columns by group of columns.  Basically a loop within a loop.

```
ldf<-data.frame(name=c("aa","bb","cc"),V1=c(10,15,10),V2=c(20,10,8),
                V3=c(8,8,9),V4=c(20,8,9),V5=c(10,15,8),V6=c(8,10,10))


anslist<-lapply(seq(2, 5, 3), function(i){
  apply(ldf[,i:(i+2)], 1, which.max)
})
answer<-t(do.call(rbind, anslist))
```

The do.call function is faster option than calling rbind for each individual result.